# Looking for a complete car list (mfg,model,year etc) for Europe

Tags: car

I am looking for a list that contains the manufacturer,model,year,engine, emission standards etc of every single model that was released in **Europe**, like the [EPA](https://www3.epa.gov/otaq/tcldata.htm) has for the US.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with maintenance, repair or engine theory.

Comment: @tlhIngan At least thank you for being productive to this conversation by sharing with us your opinion, unlike the others. Having a formal list is essential for **maintainance and repair**. If someone is trying to do the above relying on outdated, not officially validated lists/programs to follow instructions and/or possibly end up buying a wrong spare part for amateur or professional purposes, then be my guest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no single car register in Europe, every country approves/registers vehicles on their own. If one vehicle if approved/registered by one country automatically every other EU country accepts that approval.

So theoretically you need to collect the data of every national car register to have a complete list.

I found the data from the German car register to be pretty large.
Perhaps those links will help you:

[Emission data details](http://www.kba.de/SharedDocs/Publikationen/DE/Fahrzeugtechnik/SV/sv221_m1_schad_pdf.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=15)

[Manufacturer and types](http://www.kba.de/SharedDocs/Publikationen/DE/Fahrzeugtechnik/SV/sv42_pdf.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=12)

[The entire statistics (In German)](http://www.kba.de/DE/Statistik/Verzeichnisse/verzeichnisse_node.html)